# Typescript concat string is showing null in the value and remove leading / trailing separator

Tags: angular, typescript

Have a json array (results) and want to concat a key value (each.name will come with A and B)

```
finalresult: string;

      for (let each of results.data) {
          this.finalresult += "; " + each.name ;
      }
```

Two issues

1. It starts the value with "null; A; B;". Looking at looks it looks like this.finalresult is "null" and thus adds it
2. If we can fix the null then also don't want ; to start with.. I tried each.name + "; " but that will also have same result at the end (don't want it in the start or end of string)

So ideal result will be "A; B"

Comment: don't set `finalresult` to `null` initially. Just set it to an empty string. Or even simpler, just do `results.data.map(each => each.name).join("; ")` without needing a loop for the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ ... Just one more query... how can I do a filter within say ```each.type === "TYPEA"``` then only do a join on ```each.name```?

Comment: `results.data.filter(each => each.type === "TYPEA").map(/*...*/).join(/*...*/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested.. did the results.data.map(each => each.name).join("; ") and worked